# SQL DATEDIFF in an sql query

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables Customers and Purchases:

**Customers** table:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+
| CustomerID | FirstName | Surname  |
+------------+-----------+----------+
|        101 | Jeff      | Smith    |
|        102 | Alex      | Jones    |
|        103 | Pam       | Clark    |
|        104 | Zola      | Lona     |
|        105 | Simphele  | Ndima    |
|        106 | Andre     | Williams |
|        107 | Wayne     | Shelton  |
|        108 | Bob       | Banard   |
|        109 | Ken       | Davidson |
|        110 | Sally     | Ivan     |
+------------+-----------+----------+
```

**Purchases** table:

```
+------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
| PurchaseId | PurchaseDate | CustomerID | ProductID |
+------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
|          1 | 2012-08-15   |        105 | a510      |
|          2 | 2012-08-15   |        102 | a510      |
|          3 | 2012-08-15   |        103 | a506      |
|          4 | 2012-08-16   |        105 | a510      |
|          5 | 2012-08-17   |        106 | a507      |
|          6 | 2012-08-17   |        107 | a509      |
|          7 | 2012-08-18   |        108 | a502      |
|          8 | 2012-08-19   |        108 | a510      |
|          9 | 2012-08-19   |        109 | a502      |
|         10 | 2012-08-20   |        110 | a503      |
|         11 | 2012-08-21   |        101 | a510      |
|         12 | 2012-08-22   |        102 | a507      |
+------------+--------------+------------+-----------+
```

**My question** (which I have been struggling with for the last 2 days): create a query that will display all the customers who purchased products after five days or more, since their last purchase.

Desired outputs:

```
+-----------+------------------+
| Firstname |   Daysdifference |
+-----------+------------------+
|  Alex     |                7 |
+-----------+------------------+
```

Comment: Why did you try so far? seems like _do my home work for me_ question, at least show some effort.

Answer (score 0):

```
select c.FirstName, t.dif as Daysdifference  from customer c
inner join 
  (
   select p1.CustomerID, 
          datediff(day,p1.PurchaseDate,p2.PurchaseDate) as dif 
    from purchases p1 
    inner join purchases p2
    on p1.CustomerID=p2.CustomerID
    where datediff(day,p1.PurchaseDate,p2.PurchaseDate)>=5
  ) t
on t.CustomerID= c.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
DECLARE @Customers TABLE (CustomerID INT, FirstName VARCHAR(30), Surname VARCHAR(30));
DECLARE @Purchases TABLE (PurchaseId INT, PurchaseDate DATE, CustomerID INT, ProductID VARCHAR(10) );
/**/
INSERT INTO @Customers VALUES
(101,'Jeff    ' , 'Smith   '),
(102,'Alex    ' , 'Jones   '),
(103,'Pam     ' , 'Clark   '),
(104,'Zola    ' , 'Lona    '),
(105,'Simphele' , 'Ndima   '),
(106,'Andre   ' , 'Williams'),
(107,'Wayne   ' , 'Shelton '),
(108,'Bob     ' , 'Banard  '),
(109,'Ken     ' , 'Davidson'),
(110,'Sally   ' , 'Ivan    ');

INSERT INTO @Purchases VALUES
(1, '2012-08-15' ,105, 'a510'),
(2, '2012-08-15' ,102, 'a510'),
(3, '2012-08-15' ,103, 'a506'),
(4, '2012-08-16' ,105, 'a510'),
(5, '2012-08-17' ,106, 'a507'),
(6, '2012-08-17' ,107, 'a509'),
(7, '2012-08-18' ,108, 'a502'),
(8, '2012-08-19' ,108, 'a510'),
(9, '2012-08-19' ,109, 'a502'),
(10,'2012-08-20' ,110, 'a503'),
(11,'2012-08-21' ,101, 'a510'),
(12,'2012-08-22' ,102, 'a507');
--
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT Pur1.CustomerID, DATEDIFF(DAY, Pur1.PurchaseDate, Pur2.PurchaseDate) Daysdifference
    FROM @Purchases Pur1 INNER JOIN @Purchases Pur2 ON Pur1.CustomerID = Pur2.CustomerID
    )
    SELECT Cus.FirstName, CTE.Daysdifference
    FROM @Customers Cus INNER JOIN CTE ON Cus.CustomerID = CTE.CustomerID
    WHERE CTE.Daysdifference >= 5;
```

Result:

```
+-----------+------------------+
| Firstname |   Daysdifference |
+-----------+------------------+
|  Alex     |                7 |
+-----------+------------------+
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/QNHL27280)**

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it like this:

1. Create a ranking based on date desc and partitioned by customer id
2. Next check date diff between consecutive ranks to find those customers

Query below

```
 ; with cte as 
(
select 
  *, 
  row_number() over(partition by CustomerID order by PurchaseDate desc) r
from 
Purchases 
)


select 
Name= c.FirstName, 
Daysdifference =datediff(d,c1.PurchaseDate, c2.PurchaseDate) 
 from 
Customers c join
cte c1 
  on c.customerid=c1.customerid
join cte c2 
  on c1.CustomerID=c2.CustomerId 
  and c1.r-1=c2.r
  and datediff(d,c1.PurchaseDate, c2.PurchaseDate) >=5
```

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/SCUQA42355)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL Server 2012 and the addition of the LAG & LEAD functions, there is no reason at all to do a self join for something like this...

Note... Ranking function can be extremely efficient compared to other methods BUT they do need the help of a proper index to perform their best (note the additional POC index in the test script).

```
CREATE TABLE #Customers (
    CustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(30),
    Surname VARCHAR(30)
    );
CREATE TABLE #Purchases (
    PurchaseId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    PurchaseDate DATE,
    CustomerID INT,
    ProductID VARCHAR(10)
    );
INSERT INTO #Customers VALUES
(101,'Jeff    ' , 'Smith   '),
(102,'Alex    ' , 'Jones   '),
(103,'Pam     ' , 'Clark   '),
(104,'Zola    ' , 'Lona    '),
(105,'Simphele' , 'Ndima   '),
(106,'Andre   ' , 'Williams'),
(107,'Wayne   ' , 'Shelton '),
(108,'Bob     ' , 'Banard  '),
(109,'Ken     ' , 'Davidson'),
(110,'Sally   ' , 'Ivan    ');

INSERT INTO #Purchases VALUES
(1, '2012-08-15' ,105, 'a510'),
(2, '2012-08-15' ,102, 'a510'),
(3, '2012-08-15' ,103, 'a506'),
(4, '2012-08-16' ,105, 'a510'),
(5, '2012-08-17' ,106, 'a507'),
(6, '2012-08-17' ,107, 'a509'),
(7, '2012-08-18' ,108, 'a502'),
(8, '2012-08-19' ,108, 'a510'),
(9, '2012-08-19' ,109, 'a502'),
(10,'2012-08-20' ,110, 'a503'),
(11,'2012-08-21' ,101, 'a510'),
(12,'2012-08-22' ,102, 'a507');

-- add POC index...
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix_POC ON #Purchases (CustomerID, PurchaseDate);

--===========================================================

SELECT 
    c.FirstName,
    p2.Daysdifference 
FROM
    #Customers c
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
            p.CustomerID,
            Daysdifference  = DATEDIFF(DAY, p.PurchaseDate, LEAD(p.PurchaseDate, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY p.CustomerID ORDER BY p.PurchaseDate))
        FROM
            #Purchases p
        ) p2
        ON c.CustomerID = p2.CustomerID
WHERE 
    p2.Daysdifference >= 5;
```

Results...

```
FirstName                      Daysdifference
------------------------------ --------------
Alex                           7
```